# Is there a way to make the bottom tab bar height go to zero for Android and iOS in a shell project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms shell application that when in the play mode changes the color and the functionality of the tabs so that they have the same color as the background so that clicking on them does nothing.

Is there a way using a custom renderer that I can reduce the height of the tab bars in iOS and Android to zero or almost zero, so I can use the additional screen real estate?

Just to clarify this is an example of the tab area at the bottom of the page that I would like to have a height of 0:

[image]

Comment: Sample code and screenshot pls

Comment: Do you want to achieve the full screen for your application? Or hide Tab Bar on navigation? You can search `xamarin forms Auto hiding Tab Bar on navigation – Wojciech Kulik` in the google. If not, can you give me a sceenshot about your needs.

Comment: That's what I am looking for but unfortunately I only see an iOS version.  Do you know if there is also an explanation of how to do this with Android?

Comment: Can you describe a bit how you are doing the navigation and when exactly do you want to hide it? When you click on another tab, when you click a specific view on the page, when you are navigating to a totally new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution for this would be set the `Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"` on the ContentPage that needs to hide the Tabbar. This will surely give you the extra screen real estate.

Do let me know for further queries!

Thank You!

Comment: Have you tested this yourself? I have seen an issue on GitHub that is still open about this flag.
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6485

Comment: Yes I tested this and it works fine for me. I don't have a Navbar and just Tabbar so it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Android, if you want to navigate to the next page, you just use:

```cs
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage( new Page1()));
}
```

If you want to return previous page, you can execute it by following code.

```cs
private async void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
}
```

Here is running GIF to illustrate the output:

[image]

Comment: Are there any update for this issue. If the answer is helpful, please mark it (click the "✔" at the top right corner of this answer ), it will help others who have similar issues.

Comment: I think he meant the tabs on the same Activity, not switching to another one Activity. Could tell how to do that with Java or Kotlin, but have no clue of Xamarin.